# waiting for angularJS http service to finish before starting next iteration of loop

Tags: angularjs

I have written a custom http service which looks a little like this:

```
.service('httpCaller', function ($http, $location) {

  var url = 'myURL'   

  var http = {

    async: function (api) {
        var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url + api,
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .success(function (call) {
            return call;
        })
        .error(function () {
            $location.path('/search');
        });
        return promise;
    }

  };

  return http;

});
```

And I need to call this service in a loop about a hundred times like so:

```
var results = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        httpCaller.async('myAPI').then(function (data) {
            results.push(data);
        });
    }
console.log(results);
```

Obviously I need to wait for each http call to finish before starting the next call, otherwise when I log 'results' to the console, it's always going to be empty because the calls haven't finished yet. I believe I need to use...

```
$q.all()
```

...but I can't figure out from the Angular documentation how to integrate that with the code I have written. Can anyone explain how I need to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store all your promises in an array and pass it to the `$q.all` function. You can then define multiple callbacks that are automatically called.

Here is an example.

```
var results = [],
    promises = [];

var promiseSuccess = function (data) {
    results.push(data);
};

var allSuccess = function (data) {
    //data contains array of all return values for promises
};

for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    promises.push(httpCaller.async('myAPI').then(promiseSuccess));
}

$q.all(promises)
    .then(allSuccess) // called when everything has been loaded
```

Comment: Hey, you answered first and this helped me figure it out, so I'll give you the answer. But using '.error' at the bottom was giving me this console error: '$q.all(...).then(...).error is not a function' and I don't know why. Removing '.error' fixed it and everything still worked. Just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: My bad, `error` and `finally` is used when the success return another promise, I updated my code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **$q.defer()** promise manager, from the **deferred API**.

**$q.defer()** get 2 methods :

- resolve(value) : which resolve our associated promise, by giving her the final value
- reject(reason) : which resolve an promise error.

So you can  store all your promises in an array, then the `$q.all()` used to create a promise that will be resolved when all the promises of the table passed as parameter will themselves be resolved.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service, $q) {

  var promises = [];

  var defer = $q.defer();

  //Process loop
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
    //Fill my promises array with the promise that Service.get() return
    promises.push(Service.get());
  }

  //Resolve all promise into the promises array
  $q.all(promises).then(function(response){
    //Create arr by maping each data field of the response
    var arr = response.map(function(elm){
      return elm.data;
    });
    //Resolve my data when she is processed
    defer.resolve(arr);
  });

  //When the data is set, i can get it
  defer.promise.then(function(data){
    //Here data is an array
    console.log(data)
  });

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($http){

    function get(num){
      //Just an example, we return a promise
      return $http.get('path_to_url');
    }

    var factory = {
      get: get
    };

    return factory;

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```